# Projection of non-Borel set in $\mathbb R$ onto a line in $\mathbb R^2$ is non-Borel.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the textbook *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss, it is claimed (without proof) that if $A\subset\mathbb R$ is a non-Borel set, then any "projection" of $A$ onto a line $\ell\subset\mathbb R^2$ is also non-Borel. I do not understand why this should be the case. Any source/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is a projection of $A$ onto a line? Do you mean $a + Au$ where $a,u\in\mathbb R^2$ with $u\ne 0$? Notice that such transformation is continuous, in fact homeomorphic.

Comment: This is not defined in detail in the book, but my understanding is a rotation and/or translation of $A\times\{0\}$.

Comment: Note that the projection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @JohnMa Unless the line is orthognal to the real axis in which case the projection is one point hence Borel :P

Comment: Riiight, the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$ is exactly the Borel sigma algebra $\mathbb R\equiv\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ inherits as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, and so if $A\times\{0\}$ were measurable, so would be $A$.

Comment: I believe the projection  means $ \{(x,y) \in l :x \in A\}$ provided that $ l$  is not perpendicular to the $x$-axis. And the problem is to show that it does not belong to the Borel algebra of $R^2$.

Comment: In any reasonable interpretation, this is false. Take for example any non-measurable set $A \subset \Bbb{R}$. Then $B := A \times \Bbb{R}$ is not Borel measurable, but the projection of $B$ onto the line $\{0\} \times \Bbb{R}$ is the whole line and thus Borel.

Answer (score 0):

The topology of $\mathbb{R}$ can be derived from any line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the subset topology. Since Borel sets are defined in terms of open sets, that should help.